# How to add and OR statement correctly

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to do a comparison of serial numbers like so 20140831-**123** or 20140831-**1234** so the form can accept our new serial numbers which contain 4 last numbers. So far I have tried an elseif statement and an or operator with no results what am I doing wrong? is there a way to change the reg expression itself to accept 3 or 4 digits at the end of the serial?

```
if($name == 'newserial1'){
        $newserial1 = $_POST['newserial1'];

        if($newserial1 != '') {
            if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]{8}-)([0-9]{3})$/', $newserial1) ||
             (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{8}-)([0-9]{4})$/', $newserial1))) {
                $result['valid'] = false;
                $result['reason'][$name] = 'Incorrect Serial Number.';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the below regex to match last 3 or 4 digits also,

```
^([0-9]{8}-)([0-9]{3,4})$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kL0fA7/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `([0-9]{8}-)` Captures  8 digits and a following `-` symbol.
- `([0-9]{3,4})` Remaining three or four digits are captured by the second group.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\d{3,4}$` to match 3 or 4 digit in the end

Here is the complete regex pattern

```
^(\d{8})-(\d{3,4})$
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hH6tZ3/6)

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d{8}                    digits (0-9) (8 times)
  )                        end of \1
  -                        '-'
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    \d{3,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 3 and 4 times)
  )                        end of \2
  $                        the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, just remove `Not` operator from your if clauses, and add matches to preg_match:

```
if($name == 'newserial1'){
    $newserial1 = $_POST['newserial1'];
    if($newserial1 != '') {
            if(preg_match('/^([0-9]{8}-)([0-9]{3})$/', $newserial1, $matches) ||
             (preg_match('/^([0-9]{8}-)([0-9]{4})$/', $newserial1, $matches))) {
                //$result['valid'] = false;
                //$result['reason'][$name] = 'Incorrect Serial Number.';
                $result['matches'] = $matches[2];
            }
    }
}
```